# Android: cannot receive Alarm inside the BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I stucked on the following:

I created simple helper which should to set alarm in the predefined time:

**In activity:**

```
  private void setAlarm() {
        // TODO: Should be moved in the short time into BaseActivity Class ()
        // Add notification
        try {
            AlarmHelper ah = new AlarmHelper(this);
            ah.setAlarm();
            Logger.i("Alarm successfully Set");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Logger.e(e.getMessage());

        }
    }
```

**Helper:**

```
public class AlarmHelper {
    private Context mCtx;

    public AlarmHelper(Context ctx) {
        mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public void setAlarm() {
        try {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 8);
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 27);

            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 52);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(mCtx, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mCtx.getSystemService(mCtx.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mCtx,1,  myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Logger.e(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Permissions:**

```
  <!-- APP PERMISSIONS -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

**Receiver**

```
   <!-- BROADCAST RECEIVERS -->
    <receiver android:name=".receiver.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
    </receiver>
```

**I tried also this:**

```
 <!-- BROADCAST RECEIVERS -->
        <receiver android:name="com.xxx.xxx.receiver.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="YOUR_NAME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>





public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            // Device battery life will be significantly affected by the use of this API.
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "TAG");
            // Acquire the lock
            wl.acquire();
            Logger.d("ALARM RECEIVED!!!");
            //Release the lock
            wl.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.e("onReceive method cannot be processed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

No exception during the **setAlarm** method execution. But **onReceive** method is never executed.

Where can be problem please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: is this receiver part of any activity ? and what is the context that is passed to AlarmHelper.

Comment: No, receiver should be standAlone part. Context is passed into constructor of the AlarmHelper.

Comment: can you try with application context rather than activity context ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set an `intent-filter` in your `receiver` :

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="YOUR_NAME" />  
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then change the line

`Intent myIntent = new Intent(mCtx, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);`

to

`Intent myIntent = new Intent("YOUR_NAME");`

Comment: I tried to pass getApplication context and set intent-filter. But result is still same.

Comment: dont use the `Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)` contructor, use the `Intent(String action)` to specify an action that the intent filter will respond to

Comment: also It might be that the action name must be in your application namespace, so something like com.youcomp.yourapp.YOUR_ACTION

Comment: I did it, but alarmReceiver is still not fired. Could You please add some working example? Maybe  is problem just in datetime (I Testing it on the Emulator)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's working withouth intent filter, try to set the time like this:

```
manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
pendingAlarm1Intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alarmIntent, 0);

....

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
// if the time is before now then add one day to it
if(calendar.getTimeInMillis()<System.currentTimeMillis())
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(calendar.getTimeInMillis()+86400000);
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingAlarm1Intent);
```

EDIT: 
and write the whole package hierarchy in the manifest file for the BroadCastReceiver, like this:

```
<application
    ....>
    <receiver android:name="hu.bendaf.AlarmReceiver"/>
    ....
</application>
```

EDIT: update codes. I am starting the alarm in one of my activity.

Comment: do you have any Security app on your test device? Because it can block the Broadcast Receivers...

Comment: No, i testing on the emulator.

Comment: I see, than I recommend to test it in a real device, emulators can work differently sometimes :S.

Comment: On the real device with the same result.

Comment: :( than I don't have any more idea, I have almost the same code and it's tested and working for me in all of the cases :(

Comment: And how did You set the intent for receiver? Could You udpate the Your code please? Because in You answer is missing registering intent for the Broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 7);
```

Java Calendar is counting from month 0, so current month should not be 8 but 7. Sorry for my mistake. Code in the answer is working correctly.